# Trouble using a Boolean function in a program

Tags: c++, function, boolean

I am having trouble using a boolean loop.  I understand that they are true/false functions, however I when I run my program, it seems to always return the "true" value. Is *main* the one setting pass = true, or is it *targetHR* that set the value to true? I am stumped.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool targetHR(int, int);

int main()
{
    int age = NULL, heartbeat;
    while (age >= 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter your age: ";                    // Receives age from the user.
        cin >> age;
        if (age < 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        cout << "enter your heart beats per minute: "; // Receives heartbeat from user.
        cin >> heartbeat;
        bool pass = targetHR(age, heartbeat);
        if (pass = true)
        {
            cout << "You are in your target heart rate." << endl;
        }
        if (pass = false)
        {
            cout << "You are not in your target heart rate." << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My goal is to have *targetHR* be the one that does the calculations, as well as tell the main function if true/false.  I want *main* to only have a response that is dependent on *targetHR*.

```
bool targetHR(int age, int heartbeat)
{
    double maxHR, minTHR, maxTHR;
    maxHR = 220 - age;
    minTHR = maxHR * 0.60;
    maxTHR = maxHR * 0.70;
    // Debugging purposes.
    // cout << "Max heartrate: " << maxHR << endl << "Min Target HR: " << minTHR << endl << "Max Target HR: " << maxTHR << endl;

    if (heartbeat < minTHR || heartbeat > maxTHR)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have tried solving the issue by changing true/false with 1/0, but that did not fix my problem, so I am assuming that is not the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it seems to always return the "true" value

Because you're not using [Comparison operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison), you're using [Assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment#Builtin_direct_assignment), which will return the value assigned for check, so `pass = true` will always be `true`, and `pass = false` will always be `false`. You should change

```
if (pass = true)
```

to

```
if (pass == true)
```

or just

```
if (pass)
```

BTW: Some compilers (such as [clang](http://rextester.com/CUXI47398)) will give warnings for it, don't ignore them.

> warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without
>   parentheses
>   note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison

Comment: Wow... I am actually rather dissapointed in myself... Thank you very much for spotting this.  At least I know I was on the right track! :)

Comment: @AaronTMaynard This is a common mistake, :) BTW, some compliers would give a warning for this, don't ignore it.

Comment: [Visual Studio will also warn about it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hw7c1he.aspx)